# Why using the st.close and con.Close()?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to this project, why and what purpose of using this `Connection.close()` and `Statement.close()` in java?

if I didn't use this means what kind of problem (error) its occurs?

I'll try to insert the data in my database without close method, its insert looks fine. then why using this?

thanks in advance...

Comment: http://bit.ly/1r8TC9D

Comment: Err, because the Javadoc specifically says you must close them?

Comment: @RGK What *I* want is an intelligible question in standard English. In this case I also want to know why a clear statement in the Javadoc doesn't satisfy you, and what is so mysterious about releasing resources when you've finished with them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't close your streams, then what you have created is called a "resource leak".

The garbage collector will not be able to free up the resources that the stream is using, and if you are not using the stream, or if you lost the reference to it (e.g. assigning a new stream to the previous stream variable reference) then those resources are then left hanging up in the air.

Problems arise, because the Java Virtual Machine, does not have infinite memory to use, and each resource leak created takes away even more memory from the JVM. So essentially if these resource leaks keep occurring while application is running, then you are at a risk of the JVM running out of memory to use and will result in a crash and will display a OutOfMemory exception. You obviously don't want the application to run out of memory and crash, so it's a good idea to not leave streams open.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read a bit of standard Java before posting a question without understanding basic Java.
To answer your question, the Java documentation tells us this:
[Statement.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)

> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources.

Same would apply for [Connection.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

It is good programming practice to close the resource's once you are done using them, in the long run it will help you.
As to your question if you don't follow it what will happen, what will happen is that it will keep on eating up the resources (socket connection will remain open, etc).
It is best you close your `ResultSet` first, then `Statement` and then `Connection`, and do it in finally block so that to make sure resource's will always get released.